# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing a windows application in 8.1 and I am getting a following error.
my application includes a procedure in which I will be moving a file from local storage to SD card.

My code is as follows

```
namespace MoveFile
{

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
    }


    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private async void btnCreateFolder_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

      await ReadFile();

      //Error is showing here

      **await WriteToFile();
    }
    public async Task WriteToFile()
    {
        // Get the text data from the textbox.


      byte[] fileBytes =    System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(this.txtSafakCount.Text.ToCharArray());

           //I got the error in this line.....showing interopservice exception

** StorageFolder knownFolder = await KnownFolders.RemovableDevices.CreateFolderAsync("bdfbdfb", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        StorageFolder sdCard = (await knownFolder.GetFoldersAsync()).FirstOrDefault();

        // Create a new file named DataFile.txt.
        var file = await sdCard.CreateFileAsync("kaaaaammmmfewfwmHoJa.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        // Write the data from the textbox.
        using (var s = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
        {
            s.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
        }
    }
    public async Task ReadFile()
    {
        // Get the local folder.
        StorageFolder local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

        if (local != null)
        {
            // Get the DataFolder folder.
            var dataFolder = await local.GetFolderAsync("DataFolder");

            // Get the file.
           await dataFolder.CreateFileAsync("DataFile.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            var file = await dataFolder.OpenStreamForReadAsync("DataFile.txt");

            // Read the data.
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(file))
            {
                this.txtSafakCount.Text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }

        }
    }

}
}
```

I want to know why this exception occurred and how it can be resolved.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it wrong - first you should get *SD card*, then create folder. As the name `KnownFolders.RemovableDevices` says **devices** (not single device) - so you get the first of them as SD card (note that Universal Apps are not only for phones). So the working code can look like this:

```
// first get the SD card
StorageFolder sdCard = (await KnownFolders.RemovableDevices.GetFoldersAsync()).FirstOrDefault();
// then perform some actions - create folders, files ...
StorageFolder myFolder = await sdCard.CreateFolderAsync("bdfbdfb", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

Note also that you also need to add *Capabilities* in *package.appxmanifest* file, and *Declarations* if you want to use files (*File Type Associations*).

You will also find more help at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn611857.aspx).

Comment: But there is no folder Created in sd card "bdfbsfb".......Is there any problem in code. I am using emulator to run the application and I have inserted the sd card using tools option....But when i check the folder there is no bdfbdfb folder......Thanks in advance

Comment: @SourabhSharma Hence you don't have an exception, then I assume that you have added FileTypeAssociations, when you debug you can step without problems? If you want to see the folder as I've checked you will have to eject the SD card, then you will see the folder, the same situation is with phone - you will have to unplug/plug the phone to refresh.

Comment: @SourabhSharma Of course your App doesn't need the 'eject' procedure to see the folder - it's only windows refresh issue. Also don't forget to [accept answers](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) when it solved your problem. Have a nice coding.

Comment: U r genious..... Now I m trying to move Mp4 file to sd card... But streamReader is not working..May be it will use binayReader... so Can you help me to Make code to Copy or Move mp4 file to another directory...Thanks in advance...

Comment: @SourabhSharma *StorageFile* has itself methods to Copy, Move, Delete. Play with them. Also please don't use comments to ask further questions.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll    Now I am builiding this app on window 8...then it is giving the error on this line          StorageFolder sdCard = (await KnownFolders.RemovableDevices.GetFoldersAsync()).FirstOrDefault();  I have to ask this question on comment because i dont have reputation to chat with u...please help me thanks in advance..

Comment: @SourabhSharma The best would be if you had asked another question at [tag:windows-8] or other appropriate. Have you tried to google, search for some solution/information? [maybe this will help](http://lunarfrog.com/blog/2012/10/27/external-storage-devices/)